# ngmin not annotating dependencies with multiple files

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs

Here's what I have in my app.js -

```
var app = angular.module("app", []);
```

And in my controller.js, I have -

```
app.service("Store", function() {
this.products = { item: "apple" };
});
app.controller("AppCtrl", function ($scope, Store) {
$scope.products = Store.products;
})
```

When I run it thru ngmin, I get this -

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);app.service('Store', function () {
  this.products = { item: 'apple' };
});
app.controller('AppCtrl', function ($scope, Store) {
  $scope.products = Store.products;
});
```

As you can see, it didn't annotate the dependencies correctly. However, if I have `var app = angular.module("app", []);` in controller.js, it works just fine -

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.service('Store', function () {
  this.products = { item: 'apple' };
});
app.controller('AppCtrl', [
  '$scope',
  'Store',
  function ($scope, Store) {
    $scope.products = Store.products;
  }
]);
```

How do I make `ngmin` work with separate files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The official [ngmin doc](https://github.com/btford/ngmin#cli-usage) states

> Ideally, you should concat all of your files, then run ngmin once on the concatenated file.

I'm not sure but I think it's a technical limitation of the library [astral-angular-annotate](https://github.com/btford/astral-angular-annotate) used by ngmin. It is too strict with modules declarations.

Where I am working, in our Gruntfile, we first concat all the files with a [grunt/concat](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-concat), and then we run [grunt/ngmin](https://github.com/btford/grunt-ngmin) over the resulting file. As a result we only need to include one `<script>` element in the body of our webapp, this is quite handy.

Comment: That did it. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction.